# Getting text between all tags in a given html and recursively going through links

Tags: c#, html, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

i have checked a couple of posts on stack overflow regarding getting all the words between all the html tags! All of them confused me up! some people recommend regular expression specifically for a single tag while some have mentioned parsing techniques! am basically trying to make a web crawler! for that i have got the html of the link i fetched to my program in a string! i have also extracted the links from the html that i stored in my data string! now i want to crawl through the depth and extract words on the page of all links i extracted from my string! i got two questions! how can i fetch the words on the each of the web pages ignoring tags and java script? secondly how would i recursively crawl through the links??

This is how am getting html in the string:

```
public void getting_html_code_of_link()
    {
        string urlAddress = "http://google.com";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;
            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            else
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }
```

and this is how am extracting link refrences from the url i give:

```
public void regex_ka_kaam()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //Regex hrefs = new Regex("<a href.*?>");
        Regex http = new Regex("http://.*?>");

        foreach (Match m in http.Matches(data))
        {
            sb.Append(m.ToString());
            if (http.IsMatch(m.ToString()))
            {

                sb.Append(http.Match(m.ToString()));
                sb.Append("                                                                        ");
                //sb.Append("<br>");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(m.ToString().Substring(1, m.ToString().Length - 1)); //+ "<br>");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to look into the HtmlAgilityPack (its API is very close to XmlDocument).

Comment: any further guidance abt it??

Comment: `fetch the words on the each of the web pages ignoring tags`..what do you want to say here..explain

Comment: it is like i provide a link to this code! i gets the html of the link in a string! the string might have refrences to other web pages in html code! like href! so i need to pick the first page get its html! get words on that page ignoring all the tags! after first page the first href link in the string that has html is fetched and get the words so on . .

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not a good choice for parsing HTML files..

HTML is not strict nor is it regular with its format..

Use [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

---

This extracts all the links from the web page

```
public List<string> getAllLinks(string webAddress)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument newdoc=web.Load(webAddress);

    return doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
              .Where(y=>y.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("http"))
              .Select(x=>x.Attributes["href"].Value)
              .ToList<string>();
}
```

---

this gets all the content excluding tags in the html

```
public string getContent(string webAddress)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc=web.Load(webAddress);

    return string.Join(" ",doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Select(x=>x.InnerText));
}
```

---

this crawls through all the links

```
public void crawl(string seedSite)
{
        getContent(seedSite);//gets all the content
        getAllLinks(seedSite);//get's all the links
}
```

Comment: my compiler aint picking up the Decendants() function saying it does not exist in the current context!