# Extracting words between all tags in html c#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting text between all tags in a given html and recursively going through links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662267/getting-text-between-all-tags-in-a-given-html-and-recursively-going-through-link)

how can i use agility pack to pull out the words and information between the tags? i just to ignore all the tags in my html code and get all the words in between those tags. The html code has been saved by me in a string! now i want to use agility pack to accomplish this??

Comment: this is similar to your previous question..you should improve your previous question and have patience for getting answers...

Comment: that one does not mention agility pack that is why i made a new question! this ones about agility pack! i have read around and heard its better than reg expression! that is what i want to know how can get my work done through agility pack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

it depends. If, for example, one tag has a class and it is unique- it is one function, but if there are multiple tags, you need to think and create your function based on tag location, another situation when there are no tags and you would have to count html elements; you might also need to loop over tabe rows for example.

Example below does similar what you need. (not sure if it still works, since if there was a change in the page layout, it might fail.) But it gives the idea and you can go from there.

PS - when asking questions please give exact problem, not the vague explanations.

```
                String openUrl = @"http://www.ebay.com/sch/-/11724/i.html?_nkw=" + some_part_number + "&_armrs=1&LH_Complete=1";

                HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
                hw.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(openUrl);

                foreach (HtmlNode nd in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@itemprop='offers']"))
                {
                    String title = "";
                    title = Regex.Split(nd.InnerHtml.ToString(), ("title='"))[1].Trim();
                    title = Regex.Split(title, "'")[0].Trim();
                }
```