# Agility Pack Descendants function issue

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
 public string getContent(string webAddress)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(webAddress);
        return string.Join(" ", doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Select(x => x.InnerText));
    }
```

Am using this function trying to check what does the function do! But am getting the exception which tells me the function Decendants does not exist in the current context! Though i have included the refrenced dll of agility pack!

Comment: Vote close is wrong. This question has nothing in common with alleged duplicate. It's not even XML related.

Comment: Do you get an exception or compilation error?

Comment: @Dialecticus oops..i marked it with a **wrong** question..Check out my ans  which he asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662267/getting-text-between-all-tags-in-a-given-html-and-recursively-going-through-link/13662514#13662514).he is definitely using old version of `htmlagilitypack` that doesnt support `descendants`

Comment: there is another thing by logic its for sure that the get link function will get all the links and returns a list which i can store! now i can easily use foreach loop to crawl i mean use each string stored in the list and then getitscontent! however it gives different exception some based on uri all related to the line in which am actually passing each string to getcontent() foreach(string t in list) getcontent(t);

Comment: @haris you need to always check that the link starts with  `http://`..that way you would avoid the uri error

Comment: tried using this word_list = na_kr.getAllLinks("http:\\\www.google.com/") says incorrect escape sequence !with the normal ("http://www.google.com") i get some of the content but it crashed later when fetching content from some reference link! secondly i could see javascript too in the content! isnt it catered as one of the tags??

Comment: @haris check out my edit for `getalllinks` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662267/getting-text-between-all-tags-in-a-given-html-and-recursively-going-through-link/13662514#13662514)

Comment: oh sorry i see ur edited post! i get some of the content for the links in the crawl but then again i get some other exceptions! also when i used any other link than google i get exception without getting any content

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20472/discussion-between-haris-and-some1-kill-the-dj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the latest version of `htmlagilitypack` which supports `LINQ` compatible collections for navigation the HTML tree

Use this [latest](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/90925) version!

Comment: Which assembly is `Descendants` from?